# Different byte length of base64 decryption

Tags: type-conversion, base64

I am trying to decode this base64 string using VB.NET

```
System.Convert.FromBase64String("AgBgVvBR0apvj88GZFp/0ontNtFIcsJoVTachX30kURDlK010Mv9/yv1yLXXr4mqII5z2Hzx9FlGxA==")
```

And it returns 58 bytes. If I convert from Base64 on any online base64 decode program I get 32 bytes..??

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your base64 string is 80 characters. Removing the two `=` padding characters, you get 78 base64 characters. Each one represents 6 bits.

**The length of the decoded string should be `78*6/8 = 58` bytes**. So, your code is producing the correct output.

The online tools you're using are probably trying to decode into a UTF-8 or ASCII printable characters (which is not the case for your input). That's why you're only seeing less bytes in the output.